# OIDC - What is the best place to generate then code_verifier and code_challenge in SPA ReactJs or at backend (Rails App)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, openid-connect

In OIDC flow (PKCE) how to generate securely the code_challenge from code_verifier.
Should I generate in ReactJs SPA or at my Rails as back end app.

I'm not sure where to generate that in SPA ReactJs or In Rails App.

- If i generate in ReactJs SPA then where to store that code_verifier in browser for next token call at /token api of IDP (okta) for security reasons?
- If i generate in backend Rails App then is there any sceurity risks involved?

Reference doc for API calling to comple PKCE flow of OIDC:
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#token

Answer (score 1):

PKCE should always be generated where the initial authentication request is issued from. So if it is done from your SPA Browser app, then it should also generate the code_verifier and code_challenge.

Comment: Click on what? where? it it your SPA app or Rails app that initiates the flow with your identity provider?

Comment: scenario for oidc PKCE flow w.r.t user:
- user clicks on login button (oidc flow starts) which replaces browser url with authorize endpoint to get *code* based on oidc config settings for url.
-- in this i should generate code_challenge from code_verifier (where to store code_verifier securely in browser so that i can make next call to /token end point to get access_token). 
-

Comment: sorry at first place add comment button was pressed unintentionally. 
I've react app that get oidc configurations for various sso providers from server (my rails app) and react app renders Login Buttons with related configurations(oidc, saml 2.0).

Comment: i then guess PKCS should be handled in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of PKCE is to ensure that the client which initiated the authorization request is the same client which eventually exchanges the authorization code for an access token. So The code verifier and challenge should be created by the client which sends those requests to the authorization server (the authorization request and the token request). It seems that in your case it's the SPA.

As for where to store the verifier, it can be safely kept in the session storage. Another way would be to store it memory (e.g. in the state of an React app) and perform the authentication flow in a popup or iframe so that your application does not have to be reloaded. (there are frontend libraries for OIDC which can perform authorization in a popup or iframe, e.g. you can have a look at the [oauth-assistant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@curity/oauth-assistant)).